# How to change the directory to look up in flyway?

Tags: flyway

Usually flyway looks in /sql for queries.

But i wana give some different location..say c:/User/Queries.

How to configure flyway to look into diff folder?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `flyway.locations`property.

Example: `flyway.locations=filesystem:c:/User/Queries`

Comment: Turns out..using '\' instead of '/' was the problem! Resolved now! Thanks!

Comment: In Windows I set it to flyway.locations=filesystem:./ for local directory

Comment: does it mean we can use another location instead of flyway installed folder?

Answer (score 5):

To pass this in command line arguments.

**For Flyway Info**

```
flyway info -locations=filesystem:./migration -user=username -password=password -url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:portNo/dBName
```

**For Flyway Migrate**

```
flyway migrate -locations=filesystem:./migration -user=username -password=password -url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:portNo/dBName
```

Comment: Thank you I was missing the `filesystem:` prefix. This was giving me a `ERROR: Unable to obtain inputstream for resource:...` error.

Comment: Glad ! You have fixed the issue.